# Writing awk to extract cpu utilization from sar command

Tags: awk, cpu-usage, sar

I am trying to extract the values of the %user,%nice etc from the output of the `sar` command.

```
sar -P ALL 1 1
```

Output of this:

```
Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 (ftizsldapp009.ftiz.cummins.com)    09/28/2015      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

02:49:40 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
02:49:41 PM     all      3.01      0.00      2.51      0.00      0.00     94.49
02:49:41 PM       0      1.98      0.00      3.96      0.00      0.00     94.06
02:49:41 PM       1      6.00      0.00      4.00      0.00      0.00     90.00
02:49:41 PM       2      2.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     97.00
02:49:41 PM       3      1.98      0.00      2.97      0.00      0.00     95.05

Average:        CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
Average:        all      3.01      0.00      2.51      0.00      0.00     94.49
Average:          0      1.98      0.00      3.96      0.00      0.00     94.06
Average:          1      6.00      0.00      4.00      0.00      0.00     90.00
Average:          2      2.00      0.00      1.00      0.00      0.00     97.00
Average:          3      1.98      0.00      2.97      0.00      0.00     95.05
```

I have written following string to get the values but this doesn't seen to work.

My Command :

```
sar -P ALL 1 1 | \
awk '{cpu=$3; pctUser=$4; pctNice=$5; pctSystem=$6; pctIowait=$7; pctIdle=$NF}' \
     '{printf "%-3s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s\n", cpu, pctUser, pctNice, pctSystem, \
       pctIowait, pctIdle}'
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 sar -P ALL 1 1 | 
 awk  'NF == 9 && $3 != "all" {cpu=$3; pctUser=$4; pctNice=$5; pctSystem=$6; pctIowait=$7; pctIdle=$NF ;
     printf "%-3s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s\n", cpu, pctUser, pctNice, pctSystem, pctIowait, pctIdle}'
```

- `NF == 9` you need to filter on nine filed (NF)
- `$3 != "all"` skip the line that summarize cpus
- no caracter but end-of-line after `|`

a more compact version

```
 sar -P ALL 1 1 | 
 awk  'NF == 9 && $3 != "all" { printf "%-3s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s\n",$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$NF}'
```

a more more compact version

```
 sar -P ALL 1 1 | 
 awk  'NF == 9 && $3 != "all" { $1=$2=$8="" ; print ; }'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The following seems to give me expected view.
sar -P ALL 1 1|awk  '{ printf "%-3s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s\n",$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8}'

I also need to put the output in format like.
all CPU %user = 51.50
0 CPU %user = 97.00

Comment: remove `&& $3 != "all"` to get the line with all cpus.

Comment: sar -P ALL 1 1 |  awk  'NF == 9 {cpu=$3; pctUser=$4; pctNice=$5; pctSystem=$6; pctIowait=$7; pctIdle=$NF ; printf "%-3s %9s %9s %9s %9s %9s\n", cpu, pctUser, pctNice, pctSystem, pctIowait, pctIdle}' 
This seems to give me the correct view. Is there a way in which i can iterate the values of cpu cores and their corresponding %user,%nice values.

I am looking for output like
0CPU %user= 68.38
1CPU %user=57.43
0CPU %nice=0.24
1CPU %nice=4.21